# WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jhipster

Os is Mac Os Maverick.

In a jhipster context (last version, 1.2.2), I get an error when I request the default application on an entity I have just generate using `yo jhipster:entity` generator.

I run a yo jhipster to create a vanilla application with mongodb as database, java 7 and nothing special.
Then I run `grunt build` and `grunt server` for hot reload on the client part and `mvn spring-boot:run` for the server side app.

When I go to the `http://localhost:8080/` url, I get the normal page. I can sign in with either the user or admin login.

I run the `yo jhipster:entity foo` to get an exemple of rest service in the back end.

When I request for the foo resource with the URL `http://localhost:8080/#/foo`, I get the page to CRUD the resource as it is said on the jhipster website.

But when I try to create a foo item with the modal form, I get an error on the back end server log ([WARN] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported).

I can't figure out how to solve this.

Do I miss something in the documentation ?

Do you have any idea, hint ?

I have the same issue using H2 as development database instead of mongodb.

Thanks.

Hervé

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to MongoDB, if you have a date field.
We will release very soon a new and improved Entity sub-generator, which should work better for you. While testing it, I had a serialization issue with MongoDB and a date field, and I corrected it in this new version. This is due to Jackson which can't serialize Joda Time dates (the correct annotations were only generated for SQL databases, not NoSQL databases)

Comment: I will do another test today but yesterday I tried with a new vanilla application with only one entity and a H2 database for developement and I had the same issue. Is there something to do after using the entity sub-generator or is it working as it is ?

Comment: I have tested with the lastest version of JHipster and It works very well with MongoDB. Everything look good so I guess you have corrected something.